# Sublime text - snippet boostrap3 col-XX

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to create a snippet in my sublime text to quickly write:

```
col-xs-XX col-sm-XX col-md-XX col-lg-XX
```

with XX a number between 1 and 12

I tried this without success:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
col-xs-$1 col-sm-$1 col-md-$1 col-lg-$1
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>col([0-9]*)</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

https://github.com/JasonMortonNZ/bs3-sublime-plugin/tree/master/grid => this one was closely what I want but they define a snippet for all numbers...

No success with the ST2 documentation or googling

Is there a solution to my problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this (rather old) [forum post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2770), RegEx isn't supported for triggers